# Question about proof with geometric sums

Tags: summation, proof-writing

I am confused on how to write proofs for geometric sums.

I think that using the well ordering principle to find the least n $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$ with $\alpha(n)$ $\ne$ $\beta(n)$ would be a good approach. I am not sure how to continue on from then. How would I write a proof for this example?

Suppose $\alpha$ $\ne$ $\beta$ $\in \{0, 2\}^\mathbb{N}$
Prove that $$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty\frac{\alpha(k)}{3^k} \ne \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty\frac{\beta(k)}{3^k}. $$

Comment: Suppose without loss of generality that $\alpha(n) < \beta(n)$. Find an upper bound for $\sum \alpha(k)3^{-k}$ and show that that is smaller than $\sum \beta(k)3^{-k}$.

Comment: What if you consider these as expansions in base $3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x$ be the first sum, and let $y$ be the second. Let $m$ be the smallest integer such that $\alpha_m \ne \beta_m$. (This is the start you suggested.)

Without loss of generality we may assume that $\alpha_m=0$ and $\beta_m=2$. Let $w=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\alpha_i}{3^i}=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} \frac{\beta_i}{3^i}$. 
Then 
$$x\le w +\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty \frac{2}{3^i}=w+\frac{1}{3^m},$$
and 
$$y\ge w+\frac{2}{3^m},$$
and therefore $x\lt y$.